# Flask request.get.args - one arg is missing

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm sending a POST request from my website with some FormData:

```
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file',file);
  formData.append('timestamp', window.performance.now())
  console.log(formData)
  console.log(window.performance.now())
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
    console.log("asdf");
  });
  xhr.open("POST", "http://flaskmin.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/receivedoc");
  xhr.send(formData);
```

Where `file` is an actual Excel file.

I'm handling it with a Flask server:

```
@app.route('/receivedoc', methods=['POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.files)
        print("Timestamp" + request.args.get('timestamp'))
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        #Do stuff with the file
```

Curiously, the server DOES receive the file, but not the timestamp. When I try to print it, I get the error `TypeError: must be str, not NoneType`. When I do `console.log(window.performance.now())` on the website, I DO see the time on the Chrome dev tools console, but it won't get to the Flask server, stays `None`. What am I missing? I've tried `formData.append('timestamp', String(window.performance.now()))`, too, didn't help.

**UPDATE**

So I added some logging, and there's some weird stuff going on. I'm doing:

```
   fileUpload: function(file) {
      console.log("fileUpload function called")      
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file',file);
      formData.append('t_stamp123', 'test123')
      console.log(formData)
      console.log(formData.files)
      console.log(formData.file)
      console.log(file)
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:7733/receivedoc");
      xhr.send(formData);
      var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

This gets called via:

```
  self.fileUpload(uploadComponentId.files[0])
```

And `uploadComponentId` is kind of a `<form>` element. So the weird thing is my console for this shows:

```
fileUpload function called
pacing-view.html:60 FormData {}
pacing-view.html:61 undefined
pacing-view.html:62 undefined
pacing-view.html:63 File(114688) {name: "GL_Details_03212018_094512.xls", lastModified: 1521640039000, lastModifiedDate: Wed Mar 21 2018 14:47:19 GMT+0100 (CET), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 114688, …}
```

And yet, the server DOES get the file and I CAN write it to the disk (I'm running everything on localhost for now)!!! Even though `formData` seems empty, the file gets through to the server, but the timestamp doesn't? Wow.

**UPDATE 2**

When I do remove the `formData.append('file',file);` line, the file does net get sent to the server, and I get an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment`. So I am definitely not sending the file somewhere else in the code, it must be with `formData`.

Comment: maybe it's a special field name. can you try naming it `tstamp` and try again?

Comment: if you can't send a regular `string` under `timestamp` field, than I cant think of anything else but this.

Comment: I renamed it `t_stamp123` in both places to be sure, didn't work :/

Comment: can you try sending 'timestamp':'test123' and let me know about how it went?

Comment: Not working either... Curious...

Comment: hmm. how about 'asd':'qwe'? So other than the `file` itself, we cant send anything next to it? Strange

Comment: I'll update the question in a sec bc this is crazy

Answer (score 1):

Ok so turns out `FormData` in a `request` can be accessed by `request.form['timestamp']`, it's NOT stored as an `arg`.

Comment: but how come u can't console.log the formdata fields into console?

Comment: when u console.log(formdata.timestamp) on js side, can you see it properly?

Comment: Nope... No idea why I can't write it to the console... Seems totally empty.

Comment: if you can successfully get timestamp on the flaskside, then it means you console.log it the wrong way.

Comment: Yeah I guess, but i don't mind to be honest... Main thing the server gets the info :D